# Parse Yaml file with external variables

Tags: java, jackson, yaml

I am trying to get some values out of a huge YAML file using Jackson and read as a tree to get the path I need.

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory())
om.readTree(file).path("connections").path("connection")
```

It fails to parse the file on the following line:

```
config.file.path: {{DIR}}/config/
```

> com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Expected a field name
> (Scalar value in YAML), got this instead:
> <org.yaml.snakeyaml.events.MappingStartEvent(anchor=null, tag=null,
> implicit=true)>  at [Source: (StringReader); line: 80, column: 18]

As I don't need this line,  is there a way to tell the parser to skip/ignore it?

Comment: Are you sure it's YAML? That is invalid/broken YAML. Also YAML doesn't have "variables". It's rare for "standard" parsers such as Jackson to be setup to parse invalid data.

Comment: It is used as a template to generate specific yaml files for different environments.
You are right, I am dealing with an invalid yaml file. I'll have to edit it before parsing with Jackson.